# FormControl is always touched on server side

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I noticed a weird behaviour in my reactive forms when using Angular Universal (SSR).
When a formcontrol is used with a "mat-radio-group" it will always have the state "touched" when rendered on the server. When I want to show validation messages only for form controls that were actually touched this will result in a short flicker of the validation message when loading the page initially.

So i have a simple component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss']
})
export class PageComponent extends BaseComponent {
  protected formGroup = new FormGroup({
    productKey: new FormControl<string | null>(null, Validators.required)
  });

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

And when I use this markup then the formcontrol is not touched on server side:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>product</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="productKey" />
  </mat-form-field>
  {{ formGroup.controls.productKey.touched }}
</form>
```

But as soon as I use a "mat-radio-group" only on server side it will have state touched:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="productKey">
    <mat-radio-button value="'A'">1</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
  {{ formGroup.controls.productKey.touched }}
</form>
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug or by design and how it can be solved? Currently I can only think of adding a condition for showing validation message which is true when it is rendered in browser, but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug indeed. I posted the error on github of the angular team, and they were so kind and fixed the bug: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27234